# Handling digital signature in network applications

Tags: security, networking, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature

## TL;DR

Do I have to sign every single message, or is there a more efficient way of verifying the origin of messages?

---

I am developing a simple crypto protocol for fun. Of course I know that in any serious project, I should just use some industry standard, like OpenSSL, but this is for learning and experimenting.

The idea is that the communicating terminals exchange RSA public keys, then using these keys they exchange an AES key securely, so that the AES key can be used to encrypt every message from this point. I have already implemented all of this, and it works fine.

The problem is: a potential attacker cannot read anything thanks to AES, but could still for example cause errors or attempt to hijack the communication or do some other nasty stuff by being man-in-the-middle (for instance she/he could copy an encrypted message and disrupt things by sending it again and again). What I need is digital signature so I can confirm that messages are coming from the valid source and I'm in luck, because I already have a working RSA implementation.

I know how digital signatures work (taking the hash of the message and encrypting it using the private key, etc.), but the only way I can think of making this work is to **sign every single message**, then check whether the signature is valid or not on the receiving side. However, I'm concerned that this will **slow** down my protocol. The whole purpose of using AES to secure the communication (or any symmetric key encryption) is that it's a lot faster than RSA (or any public key encryption). Wouldn't doing this **defeat the purpose of AES** (or any symmetric key encryption)? So the question is: **do I have to sign every single message?** Or is there a more efficient way of doing this? How does for example OpenSSL handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR Use [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AEAD_block_cipher_modes_of_operation).**

In symmetric encryption it is possible to produce a Message Authentication Code (MAC) that enables you to check whether a message that you sent was (maliciously) manipulated. A man-in-the-middle attacker has only a negligible advantage of forging an authentication tag for a message that you haven't tagged.

There are many ways of doing this, but it's generally seen that a MAC should authenticate the ciphertext and not the plaintext ([Should we MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-MAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022)). Popular MAC algorithms are HMAC (e.g. HMAC-SHA256), CMAC/OMAC1 or GMAC. There are also some distinct authenticated modes such as GCM, EAX, OCB, SIV, CWC, etc. Those combine a mode to achieve confidentiality and a mode for authenticity without the need of different keys for both.

But this is not enough because this only enables the receiver to detect tampering or forgeries of messages. An attacker may still mount other attacks such as replay or delay attacks. Therefore you need to send nonces (such as a message counter) and time stamps along. The receiver would have to keep a record of previously sent messages (by storing the nonces) and not accept any messages that are sent too late judging by its internal clock.

In order to prevent the attacker from changing the nonces and time stamps at will, those also have to be authenticated. Most authenticated modes are actually *Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data* which can authenticate additional non-secret data such as nonces and time stamps.

The use of authenticated encryption can make a purely symmetric communication relatively tamper-proof under the assumption that the key was exchanged confidentially and was also verified through conventional digital-signatures such as RSA-PSS or Ed25519 (EdDSA).

Comment: Thanks! I finally went with AES GCM as TLS 1.2 also seems to be using it.